# WCF REST method and non-REST method

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Service that I need one of my methods accept HTTP POST request and the other one must be non-REST. Consider the code below:

```
        [OperationContract]
        long[] Send(string body, List<string> phoneNumbers);


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        long[] SendByPost(string body, string phoneNumbers);
```

But I don't know why the error below is raised:

> Operation 'Send' of contract 'IService' specifies multiple request
>   body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most
>   one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either
>   remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think the issue is with `List<string> phoneNumbers`.  By default the WebInvoke is a `GET`, but `List<string>` cannot be deserialized from the URL.  I think if you change it to `string[] phoneNumbers` should work.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want Send method be available from URL and only the second method must be REST enabled!

Comment: Then remove the `OperationContract` attribute.

Comment: @wdosanjos he can not remove OperationContract

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to send multiple parameters in a url, you can use **GET** method instead of **POST**.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
long[] SendByGet(string body, string phoneNumbers);
```

Either change it into this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/body={body}?phoneNumbers={phoneNumbers}"]
long[] SendByPost(string body, string phoneNumbers);
```

Or if you want to use **POST**.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
UriTemplate = "MyUrl", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
long[] SendByPost(Info info);
```

And here is your **Info** class:

```
[DataContract]
Class Info
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Body {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public string PhoneNumbers{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter with HTTP Method he uses.

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods and you want to expose one of them to REST and the other to another binding, right?

For this, you need to create more than one interface for your wcf service ([ServiceContract]).

Take, for example, this Web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestBinding" maxBufferSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="1048576" maxArrayLength="1048576" maxBytesPerRead="1048576" maxNameTableCharCount="1048576"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SoapBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000" maxArrayLength="20000000"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
      <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="WCFService.RawContentTypeMapper, WCFService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Buffered" /><!--transferMode="Streamed"-->
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WCFService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="WCFService.ServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5000"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding" contract="WCFService.IService1" name="SOAP_XML"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" contract="WCFService.IService2" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointJSONBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="MTOM" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IService1" name="SOAP_MTOM"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFService.ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointXMLBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="EndpointJSONBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="EndpointRawBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

You can see here two ServiceContracts: **IService1** and **IService2**.

To run methods defined in IService1 you need to use soap encapsulation.
Methods exposed by IService2 can be called RESTfully and easily without soap
encapsulation.

For your SendByPost() method to be RESTful you need to put it in IService2 and put the other method in a different ServiceContract (like IService1).